# Would it break any browsers if : didn't get replaced with %3A in hyperlinks?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

When linking to the Perldoc pages of Perl Modules, the links get heavily modified. This is mainly because of the use of `::` to separate namespaces.

For example this is how I like to link to the Perldoc pages of Modules:

```
Perldoc link to
[Moose::Meta::Role::Application::ToInstance][]

[Moose::Meta::Role::Application::ToInstance]:
  http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Moose::Meta::Role::Application::ToInstance
```

Perldoc link to [Moose::Meta::Role::Application::ToInstance](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Moose::Meta::Role::Application::ToInstance)

If you hover over the link you will see that it gets transformed into a link to

```
http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Moose%3a%3aMeta%3a%3aRole%3a%3aApplication%3a%3aToInstance
```

Which needless to say, is very hard to read.

I would like to point out, that StackOverflow didn't use to do this.

---

The thing is, I don't think this is necessary.

So I would like to know which versions of which browsers fail to work when this is pasted into the address bar.

```
http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Moose::Meta::Role::Application::ToInstance
```

---

If there aren't any "modern" <sup><sub>( made this century )</sub></sup> browsers that this fails to work correctly for, I plan on making this a [feature-request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request).

Comment: Blame chrome for ugly URL displays. Firefox makes it look pretty...

Comment: I don't think any browsers will break over this, but other clients *might* (although it is my understanding that they shouldn't, because `:` has a special meaning in the host name only.) I personally would tend to play it safe and use `_` instead of `::` or something.

Comment: It appears this only affects posts, not comments [Moose::Meta::Role::Application::ToInstance](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Moose::Meta::Role::Application::ToInstance)

Comment: @Pekka The url is a redirecting link. Currently it redirects to `http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/Moose-1.24/lib/Moose/Meta/Role/Application/ToInstance.pm` but that will change automatically when a new version is available. It is in wide use, so changing it isn't really practicable.

Answer (score 6):

`;`, `/`, `?`, `:`, `@`, `&`, `=`, `+`, `$`, and `,` are all Reserved characters in URIs.

Reserved characters are not allowed in the scheme, authority, or path portion of the URI according to [RFC2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt).  However, they appear to be allowed in the query component (the part following the `?`)

For reference, the section of the URI you're referring to is the Path portion.

UPDATE:

There is a newer RFC for URIs, [RFC3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt).  However, it also appears not to allow `:` in the path section of the URI.  The others are up for interpretation, as RFC3986 allows sub-delimiters (`!`, `$`, `&`, `'`, `(`, `)`, `*`, `+`, `,`, `;` and `=`) in certain circumstances.

Comment: I realize this answer doesn't actually answer the question, but it's supposed to be more of a "don't do it because the standard says don't do it."